# Postgresql: syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.3

How to properly add an aggregation column of units (sprd_units)?
It should sum units by mrkt_desc, offer_seq_yr_nr, offer_seq_nr_desc and sprd_nr. I get the error: "subquery must return only one column"
What am I doing wrong? 
Here is the query.

```
SELECT     
    d.mrkt_desc_txt, 
    d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr, 
    d.brchr_qtr_nr, 
    d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
    d.offr_cmpgn_nr, 
    d.veh_desc_txt, 
    d.sls_cls_desc_txt, 
    CASE WHEN d.veh_desc_txt='CORE BROCHURE' THEN d.sprd_nr ELSE cb.sprd_cb END AS sprd_nr,
    (SELECT 
        d.mrkt_desc_txt,
        d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr,
        d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
        d.sprd_nr,
        sum(d.unit_qty) AS sprd_units
    FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail d
    WHERE d.veh_desc_txt::text = 'CORE BROCHURE'::text OR d.veh_desc_txt::text = 'GENERAL REPRESENTATIVES FLYER'::text
    GROUP BY 
        d.mrkt_desc_txt,
        d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr,
        d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
        d.sprd_nr) as sprd_units
    d.sub_clstr_desc_txt,
    c.prod_typ_desc_txt, 
    c.bus_desc_txt, 
    c.ce_new_cat, 
    c.ce_new_cat_short, 
    c.catgry_desc_txt, 
    c.sgmt_desc_txt, 
    c.form_grp_desc_txt, 
    c.form_desc_txt,
    c.brnd_desc_txt, 
    c.brnd_postnng_fr_desc_txt, 
    c.gendr_desc_txt,
    vc.wrkhrs_grp,
    vc.brnd_fmly_desc_txt_adj,
    round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST' THEN d.profit_amt/f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS dp_dol_FLL, 
    round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN d.profit_amt/f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS dp_dol_BOP, 
    round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST' THEN d.spcl_prc_grs_sls_amt::double precision / f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS gr_sales_dol_FLL,
    round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN d.spcl_prc_grs_sls_amt::double precision / f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS gr_sales_dol_BOP,
    sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) AS units_FLL,
    sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) AS units_BOP
    FROM       
    ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail as d
    JOIN ext_ce.gsam_v_data_context as c
        ON (c.prmry_prfl_cd::numeric = d.prmry_prfl_cd)
    JOIN ext_ce.info_fx_rates_v2 as f
        ON ( d.mrkt_desc_txt = f.mrkt_desc_txt)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT g.prmry_prfl_cd, g.wrkhrs_grp, g.brnd_fmly_desc_txt_adj FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_context AS g) AS vc
        ON vc.prmry_prfl_cd = d.prmry_prfl_cd
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.mrkt_desc_txt, d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr, d.offr_seq_nr_desc, d.prmry_prfl_cd, min(d.sprd_nr) AS sprd_cb
    FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail d
    WHERE d.veh_desc_txt::text = 'CORE BROCHURE'::text
    GROUP BY d.mrkt_desc_txt, d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr, d.offr_seq_nr_desc, d.prmry_prfl_cd) cb ON d.mrkt_desc_txt::text = cb.mrkt_desc_txt::text AND d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr = cb.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr AND d.offr_seq_nr_desc = cb.offr_seq_nr_desc AND d.prmry_prfl_cd = cb.prmry_prfl_cd
    WHERE      
    c.prod_typ_desc_txt <> 'SALES AIDS'::text 
    AND d.cnsmr_invstmt_bdgt_desc_txt::text <> 'Sampling'::text 
    AND c.prmry_prfl_cd::numeric = d.prmry_prfl_cd
    AND f.offr_cmpgn_yr_nr = 2017
    AND d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr > 2014
    AND d.mrkt_desc_txt = f.mrkt_desc_txt
    GROUP BY   
    d.mrkt_desc_txt, 
    d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr, 
    d.brchr_qtr_nr, 
    d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
    d.offr_cmpgn_nr, 
    d.veh_desc_txt, 
    d.sls_cls_desc_txt, 
    d.sprd_nr,
    bs.sprd_units,
    d.sub_clstr_desc_txt,
    c.prod_typ_desc_txt, 
    c.bus_desc_txt, 
    c.ce_new_cat, 
    c.ce_new_cat_short, 
    c.catgry_desc_txt, 
    c.sgmt_desc_txt, 
    c.form_grp_desc_txt, 
    c.form_desc_txt,
    c.brnd_desc_txt, 
    c.brnd_postnng_fr_desc_txt, 
    c.gendr_desc_txt,
    vc.wrkhrs_grp,
    vc.brnd_fmly_desc_txt_adj,
    cb.sprd_cb;
```

I forgot to add. I use Postgresql 8.3

Comment: you have a comma after `FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail d,`, remove it

Comment: @Lamak is right, But also you wont be able to return multiple fields on that `SELECT` and your query is incomplete

Comment: right, now I got "subquery must return only one column' error

Comment: well, now you should post the complete query

Comment: Juan, what do you mean?

Comment: Ok I will try. It quite large

Comment: Exactly what you got. Your inner `SELECT` return multiple fields and you cant do that.

Comment: My inner SELECT should produce only "sprd_units". I don't get it

Comment: sprd units is a column with units but aggregated by d.mrkt_desc_txt,
        d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr,
        d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
        d.sprd_nr

Comment: I have added the full code

Comment: So your inner select produces 5 fields. You have 5 fields in that select statement. PErhaps you should wrap that up in it's own select like `(SELECT sprd_units FROM (<current inner select>) innerselect) as sprd_units` Or take those fields out of the inner select's `SELECT` clause leaving them in the GROUP BY.

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: "subquery must return only one column' this is an error. I wrote it in a comment, sorry

Comment: @JNevil, could you please give more details: "take those fields out of the inner select's SELECT clause leaving them in the GROUP BY" ?

Comment: You have one sub query, which uses a group by. You can only return ONE column with the SELECT. So you want `SELECT sum(d.unit_qty) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...`  and leave the `GROUP BY` part unchanged just as it is.

Comment: @flutter, so when I do: (SELECT 
   sum(d.unit_qty) AS sprd_units
  FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail d
        WHERE d.veh_desc_txt::text = 'CORE BROCHURE'::text OR d.veh_desc_txt::text = 'GENERAL REPRESENTATIVES FLYER'::text
  GROUP BY 
   d.mrkt_desc_txt,
   d.offr_seq_cmpgn_yr_nr,
   d.offr_seq_nr_desc,
   d.sprd_nr ) as sprd_units              I get:syntax error at or near "("

Comment: Do you have a comma before and after your sub-select?
`SELECT a, b` **, COMMA** `(SELECT ... GROUP BY ...) AS sprd_units` **, COMMA** `x, y, z`?
Do you have a closing parenthesis for each opening parenthesis?